# How to align objects to the center of another object

Tags: groups, object-mode

I am new to Blender (2.8) and trying to model a kind of turret, to try and learn by myself.

I am encountering a rather simple problem : I have placed 4 cannons relative to one another, and would like to align their center to the body of the turret (the grey elongated cube behind the cannons).

I would like to align them to the body of the cannon, either by :

1. Distributing them all along the length of the grey cube. (on the x axis)
2. Moving the cannons "as a whole" to the center of the cube.

I believe this should be simple, and has probably been answered before but I can't find where so I apologize.

[image: The cannons and the turret body]

Comment: Array modifier with object offset perhaps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The way to solve this is pretty simple:

In the **3D Viewport Window (Shift + F5)**, select the objects you want to align (Shift + Click). At the top of the Window (beside "Object Mode" etc. selection), go to the **Object tab**, and select **Transform**.

This will give you another drop-down menu, which at the bottom has the option **Align objects**. Select this, and a menu will appear on the bottom left. It will show some options for aligning the selected objects. Play around with these settings until you have a pleasing result. You can also Shift-click on the x,y, and z align options to align on multiple axes at the same time.